# Crystal XI - Include a group total for values where the group field is null

Tags: visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports, grouping

I'm using Crystal Reports for VS2010, programmatically generating the identity of the 'group-by' fields at run time using VB.NET in a WinForms application.

Two group-by fields - the outer total is correct, and the inner sub-totals are correct, but no sub-total is shown for all the detail records that don't have a value for the group-by field.

So for instance, grouping by Country, where the address in the detail records don't have a value for country.

It just makes the report look stupid, since the sub-totals don't add up to the totals.

Is there an easy way of generically including a sub-total for the ones that don't have the group-by value?

Comment: It's quite difficult to understand what you mean here - is it the sub-grouping that is not being shown when the inner group is null, so that the outer group totals add up to more than the displayed sub-totals, or is it the outer group totals not being shown when the outer group is null - if the latter, are inner group sub-totals shown for a null outer group? In your example, is Country an inner group or an outer group?

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear.  It's the former of your two options!  I'll check the properties you suggest - thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds as though some of your sections are being conditionally suppressed on whether the group is null. I suggest you open the report in the Crystal Reports designer, and check the Section Expert (either select [image] from the toolbar or right-click in the grey margin to the left of the report layout area and select Section Expert) for each section to see whether the relevant sections are being conditionally suppressed (the `x-2` button next to Suppress would be coloured red).

It would also be worth checking whether any sections are being suppressed programmatically, and whether any of the sections are being suppressed when blank (although if a sub-total is displayed even in sections with null group values, this shouldn't matter).